# Unable to render charts using Wicked PDF

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, d3.js, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to render an HTML page to PDF using wicked_PDF. The page contains several charts that I create using D3.js. On the PDF, only the axes of the charts are visible. The body of the chart is blank. 
I tried to convert the SVG to both a Canvas and a PNG image (encoded using Base64). IN both cases, the images display as HTML, but only the axes are shown in the PDF.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a resolution to this problem?

Comment: Since posting and I've managed to get this working - do you happen to need a solution still? There were like 3-4 gotchas along the way so unfortunately, I don't know if there is a magic bullet I could write out in this comment, but I'm happy to help if I can.

Comment: While I don't need the solution myself, I'm sure it will help someone else.

Comment: True enough - the 4 major things I did to fix this for us were: (1) Not using the middleware approach and instead using one off ruby embedded pdfs based off of a PDF layout you create, (2) using wicked_pdf's asset helpers to load ONLY the javascript we needed on those pages for assets we store in the app (all CDN based assets can be loaded with a normal javascript_include_tag), (3) using the javascript_delay option, (4) and (potentially not relevant but important) we use Chartkick (not D3), but we needed to pass the "discrete" axis option otherwise we only saw the axis and no data.

Comment: Decided to post a more complete solution on another question more specifically related to my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342516/chartkick-charts-do-not-show-when-rendering-to-pdf-using-wicked-pdf/28972109#28972109

Answer (score 2):

Is seems that javascript does not work before rendering PDF.

First, be sure that it is enabled on rendering PDF. According to [link](http://rubydoc.info/github/mileszs/wicked_pdf/frames), there exists option `:disable_javascript   => false` to `render :pdf`.

Next, all assets must be included with absolute urls. According to the same link,

> You must define absolute paths to CSS files, images, and javascripts; the best option is to use the wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag, wicked_pdf_image_tag, and wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag helpers.

Comment: I tried that, but there was no effect.
I'm pretty sure the javascript is running, since the axes are being printed. Only the chart content is missing. The content renders correctly when I enable the show_as_html option. This makes me believe that the pdf rendering is off.

Comment: Anyone find a resolution here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like graph is not fully rendered but and wickedpdf is snapping the page in between. So you can use an option to wait till the java script fully runs and render the graph.

> :javascript_delay => 10000

now wicked pdf will wait for 10 seconds.

Note : This will only work for version 0.12.1 of wkhtmltopdf.